# Sending images using Paho Mqtt on a Debian 11 Bullseye and a Raspberry pi 4

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I am working on a project where i want to send an image over mqtt and I am currently using mosquitto as a broker. My device is running on a Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye).

My mqtt client is working normally with paho and i can perfectly send string as my message payload. The problem is when i try to send an image (as bytearray) as a message. The tuple returned from the publish method indicates that the message sending the bytearray was successful ((0,1)), but neither the broker nor my other script running a mqtt client subscripted to the topic which the image was published received anything.

IMPORTANT: I also tried running the same python script, sending the same image on a Raspberry Pi 4 and it worked just fine. I saw the publish on my broker and my other script running a mqtt client also received it. Both Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) and Raspberry Pi 4 were running with the same paho_mqtt version (1.6.1)

Are images built in different ways depending on the linux distribution?

**Image Sender Client:**

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt, time

BROKER = "***.***.*.***"
CAMID = "Clinux"

class MyMqtt:
    def __init__(self, broker, clientId):
        self.broker = broker
        self.clientId = clientId

    def run(self):
        self.client = mqtt.Client(client_id=self.clientId)
        self.client.loop_start()

        connectionSuccess = False
        while connectionSuccess == False:
            try:
                self.client.connect(self.broker)
                connectionSuccess = True
                print("Connected!\nbroker: ",self.broker)
            except:
                print("Unable to connect to ", self.broker)
                time.sleep(1)

        self.client.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.client.on_disconnect = self.on_disconnect
        self.isConnected = True

    def Disconnect(self):
        self.client.disconnect()
        self.client.loop_stop()

    def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc):
        self.Image()

    def on_disconnect(self, client, userdata, rc):
        if rc != 0:
            print("Unexpected disconnection.")
        else:
            print("Successfully Disconnected")
        self.isConnected = False

    def Publish(self, topic, message, qos = 0, retain = False):
        return self.client.publish(topic, message, qos, retain)

    def Subscribe(self, topic, callbackFunction):
        self.client.subscribe(topic)
        self.client.message_callback_add(topic, callbackFunction)

    def Image(self):
        try:
            f=open("sample.png", "rb") #3.7kiB in same folder
            fileContent = f.read()
            byteArr = bytearray(fileContent)
            print(self.Publish("Image", byteArr))
        except Exception as e:
            print("erro")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mqttClient = MyMqtt(BROKER, CAMID)
    mqttClient.run()

    while mqttClient.isConnected == True:
        print("on loop")
        time.sleep(1)
```

**Image Receiver Client:**

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt, time

BROKER = "***.***.*.***"
CAMID = "CPC"

class MyMqtt:
    def __init__(self, broker, clientId):
        self.broker = broker
        self.clientId = clientId

    def run(self):
        self.client = mqtt.Client(self.clientId)
        self.client.loop_start()

        connectionSuccess = False
        while connectionSuccess == False:
            try:
                self.client.connect(self.broker)
                connectionSuccess = True
                print("Connected!\nbroker: ",self.broker)
            except:
                print("Unable to connect to ", self.broker)
                time.sleep(1)

        self.client.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.client.on_disconnect = self.on_disconnect
        self.isConnected = True

    def Disconnect(self):
        self.client.disconnect()
        self.client.loop_stop()

    def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc):
        self.Subscribe("Image", self.ReceiveImage)

    def on_disconnect(self, client, userdata, rc):
        if rc != 0:
            print("Unexpected disconnection.")
        else:
            print("Successfully Disconnected")
        self.isConnected = False

    def Publish(self, topic, message, qos = 0, retain = False):
        self.client.publish(topic, message, qos, retain)

    def Subscribe(self, topic, callbackFunction):
        self.client.subscribe(topic)
        self.client.message_callback_add(topic, callbackFunction)

    def ReceiveImage(self, client, userdata, message):
        try:
            f = open('output.jpg', "wb")
            f.write(message.payload)
            print("Image Received")
            f.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e.message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mqttClient = MyMqtt(BROKER, CAMID)
    mqttClient.run()

    while mqttClient.isConnected == True:
        print("on loop")
        time.sleep(1)
```

**UPDATE:**

I just found out that the problem is on the maximum packet size. There is some kind of limit on the message size on the Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye). When i publish a string longer than 1931 bytes the same effect as the image. I also published a 400 bytes image and it worked. How can this limit be set?

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? What output messages do you see? Have you tried using the `mosquitto_sub` command to see what messages are being published?

Comment: Also just checking, you mention testing on a Raspberry Pi, since you have hard coded client ids you can only have one instance of each script connected to the broker at any time.

Comment: I first tried to publish the byte array. The publish result was (0,1) but the broker prompt only displayed the "new client connection". Then, i tried to send a string instead of the byte array on the same script and the same topic. The publish result was also (0,1) but this time i could see it on the broker prompt and my receiving script also received it:
"Received PUBLISH from Crasp (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'Image', ... (7 bytes))"

Comment: Then i tried publishing both byte array and string (this exact order). The publish result was (0,1) and (0,2) but the broker didn’t recognize any of the pubishes
Then I inverted the publishing order (string first, bytearray after). The publish result was also (0,1) and (0,2) but now the broker recognize the publish with the string, since it was the first.
I believe there is some problem with sending the byte array, but my try catch got nothing and the publish result was successful

Comment: And yes, i am aware there cant be clients with the same ID. I hardcoded them, but with unique id's. 
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you sure this only affects MQTT? (try transferring a file using `scp` or similar). I have seen similar issues caused by a misconfigured [MTU](https://mike632t.wordpress.com/2019/03/03/determine-mtu-size-using-ping/); this is relatively rare and easy to miss (`ssh` works fine until you try to `cat` a large file). Might not be your issue (you don't mention how the devices are networked) but worth checking that this is an MQTT specific issue and not something impacting all TCP traffic.